# python3.4.2 email BODY Chinese decoding/encoding

Tags: email, python-3.x

I am writing a script using Python3.4.2 to extract emails from my gmail box.  Some of the emails are in Chinese.
I can print out the SUBJECT of my email in Chinese using the following code ,

```
email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(msg['subject']))
```

However, I don't know how to print out the BODY of my email in Chinese.  I tried to use the code in the following link,
https://gist.github.com/miohtama/5389146

However, **`the unicode() function`** is not available in **`Python3.4.2`**.  I tried to replace it with str() function, but it does not work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 strings are unicode by default, you don't need to call `unicode()`.

If you call `str()` over a text with chinese characters it will fail as `str()` (also called `bytes()` in Python 3) have 1 byte per character.

Comment: r, d = m.fetch(emailid,"(UID BODY[TEXT])")
            #body = get_decoded_email_body(d[0][1])
            print(d[0][1])    It prints the following,    b'--bcaec53d51d34157a0050c2ff08c\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nYm9keSDlhoXlrrnmtYvor5UNCg==\r\n--bcaec53d51d34157a0050c2ff08c\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nPGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI+Ym9keSDlhoXlrrnmtYvor5U8ZGl2Pjxicj48L2Rpdj48L2Rpdj4NCg==\r\n--bcaec53d51d34157a0050c2ff08c--'

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fernando.  The Chinese should be  'body 内容测试'